# Postscript output vertically compressing figure, but not PDF

Tags: r

I have some R code that produces a map. If I obtain PDF output, the map looks as it should.  However, if I change the output device to postscript (ps or eps), the map gets vertically compressed thereby scrambling the output.

Do I need to give any additional instructions to R when outputting ps or eps formats?  I could post the code here, but its rather complicated and I don't know if I can come up with a smaller example code.

I am faced with this since PlosONE requires submission in only eps or tiff formats.  I also tried converting from pdf to ps and ps2eps, but that crops all the margins and outermost parts of the figure.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots as I can't quite visualise how vertical compression would give a scrambled output. Secondly, have you tried changing the height and width in the ps or eps device?

Comment: @sebastian-c I kept the same dimensions for height and width for ps and eps output as I did for pdf output.  By scrambling I meant displacement of various items in the map e.g. legends, labels, lines, arrows, arrowheads, insets.  Figure width is maintained, but height is not.  I will try to post screenshots.

Comment: If you can produce a small chunk of code that we could use to reproduce the problems on our machines, that would also go a long way towards solving the problem.